# Destacar termo buscado em negrito com ou sem acento

Tags: php, mysql, autocompletar, preg-replace

Olá amigos gostaria muito da ajuda de vocês. estou tentando destacar as palavras  digitada em negrito no busca. o código abaixo funciona apenas se digitar "selecao brasileira" mais se digitar "selecao de futebol" nada acontece. agradeço desde já a ajuda.. abraços..

```
//$post = "selecao de futebol"; //não funciona
$post = "selecao brasileira"; //funciona

$dados_mysql = "seleção brasileira de futebol";

$post = preg_replace('/[aáàâãäeéèêiíìoóòôõöuúùücç]/','(a|á|à|â|ã|ä|e|é|è|ê|i|í|ì|o|ó|ò|ô|õ|ö|u|ú|ù|ü|c|ç)',$post);
$resultado = preg_replace("/($post?)/i","<b>\\0</b>",$dados_mysql);

echo "$resultado";
```

Comment: Poste o código completo.

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta, usei outra função.. Dá uma olhada

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você quer retirar acentos e deixar lowerCase? Se for, a função lower() faz isso para você. Depois disso, você tem que executar **preg_replace** para cada palavra (senão só iria dar *match* caso as duas palavras estivessem seguidas tanto no *post* quando no *dados_mysql*), então tem que fazer um **explode**. A função findWords() faz isso para você.

Faz assim:

```
function lower($string) {
    $string = mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8');
    $string = preg_replace('/[`´^~\'"]/', null, iconv( 'UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string ) );
    return $string;
}

function findWords($string1, $string2) {
    $stringLow1 = lower($string1);
    $stringLow2 = lower($string2);

    $stringLow1 = explode(" ", $stringLow1);

    foreach ($stringLow1 as $string) {
        $stringLow2 = preg_replace("/($string?)/i","<b>\\0</b>", $stringLow2);
    }

    $string2 = explode(" ", $string2);
    $stringLow2 = explode(" ", $stringLow2);

    foreach ($stringLow2 as $key => $string) {
        if (preg_match("/<b>/", $string)) {
            $string2[$key] = '<b>' . $string2[$key] . '</b>';
        }
    }

    $string2 = implode(" ", $string2);

    return $string2;
}

$dados_mysql = "seleção brasileira de futebol";
$digitado = "seleção de futebol";

echo findWords($digitado, $dados_mysql);
```

Obs: analisou a possibilidade de fazer isso no Front-end? É a minha sugestão.

Comment: Muito grande para colocar num comentário, editei a resposta.

Comment: Nossa.. perfeito.. já é o 7° dia que tento fazer isso e você  resolve em poucos minutos. você esta de parabéns.. abraços..

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar desenvolver usando a função `strripos`:

```
$termo_pesquisa     = 'ababcd';
$buscar             = 'ab';
$pesquisar          = strripos($termo_pesquisa, $buscar);

if ($pesquisar === false) {
    echo "Sinto muito, nós não encontramos ($termo_pesquisa) em ($buscar)";
} else {
    echo "Parabéns!\n";
    echo "Nós encontramos a <strong>($buscar)</strong> em ($termo_pesquisa) na posição ($pesquisar)";
}
```

Se houver dúvidas você pode dar uma lida na documentação também: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strripos.php

Comment: Opa André tudo bem. obrigado pela resposta. mais o problema é que estou usando um autocomplete com este meu código. mais mesmo assim obrigado..